# Set function property from within object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am declaring `tasks` object:

```
var tasks = {

    test: () => {
        /// ....
    }

};
```

From within the `test` function, I want to set `tasks.test.description` property. So far I have tried:

```
var tasks = {
    test: () => {
        // need to set tasks.test.description here
        // 
        // tried without success:
        // tasks.test.description = '...';
        // this.description = '...';
        // arguments.callee.description = '...';
    }
};
```

as well as:

```
var tasks = {
    test: function xxx() {
        // all methods from example above, plus:
        // xxx.description = '...';
    }
};
```

The description always becomes undefined when accessing from outside the function scope.

```
console.log(tasks.test.description); // => undefined
```

Is there a way to set description property from within the function definition inside the object literal?

Comment: To understand what you're doing please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `tasks.test.description` the way to go. Will work.

Comment: And you realize that code in a function just runs when the function was called?

Comment: Please, you need to clarify what you're trying to do!

Comment: @Ele I am trying to declare an object and set `test` property to a function and set `description` property of that function to a string. I would like to do that by using one statement (which is object declaration pasted above).  If this is not possible, I am fine with it, no need to downvote just because the answer is "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might use Object.assign to combine the function with an object:

```
 test: Object.assign(() => {
    /// ....
  }, {
   description: "whatever"
 })
```

Comment: Wait, the OP stated this: *From within the test function, I want to set tasks.test.description property.*  How this answers the question?

Comment: @ele what the OP wants is impossible.

Comment: I totally agree with you, however, this answer is not helping.  You could put that information and make a reference about this alternative, I think.

Comment: Seems to be the most creative answer even though my question was probably somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: @ele *this answer is not helping* ... :)

Comment: hehehehe unclear question leads unclear accepted answer `:)`... Have a good day!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is almost correct, but you have to **call** the function before it will do anything.

```js
var tasks = {
  test: () => {
    tasks.test.description = '...';
  }
};
tasks.test();
console.log("The value of tasks.test.description is " + tasks.test.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that console.log(tasks.test.description); returns undefined is you defined object, but description property will be create until you first run tastks.test() method. To add property description to object method try this:

```
const tasks = {
  test() {
    //....
  }
};

tasks.test.description = 'asd';
```

Or

```
const tasks = {
  test() {
    this.test.description = 'asd';
  }
};

tasks.test();

console.log(tasks.test.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your attempt is almost right. You just need to call `tasks.test()` to set `tasks.test.description`.

```js
var tasks = {
    test: function xxx() {
        xxx.description = '...';
    }
};

tasks.test();
console.log(tasks.test.description);
```

If you want to set that property without calling `test` [the answer by Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541341/9058464) is the way to go.